# String.format working in console but not JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

I thought I was just being an idiot about this, and no doubt I still am, but this code:

```
String name = (String)getValueAt(selectedRow,0)+" "+(String)getValueAt(selectedRow,1)+
                " "+(String)getValueAt(selectedRow,2);   
String city = ((String)getValueAt(selectedRow,4));
String message = String.format("Name: %30s\nCity: %30s", name, city);
System.out.println(message);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CandidateTable.this, message);
```

Results in this in the console, the formatting I want:

[image]

but this, in the JOptionPane:

[image]

I've searched for a solution here and google, and looked through the oracle tutorial and docs, but can't seem to find anything, which makes me think I'm making a silly error.

Am I?

Comment: Your console uses a [fixed-width font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), the option pane doesn't.

Comment: Use a monospaced font in the option pane.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot

Comment: @Andrew Thompson is a monospaced font a good way to format the pane? it's looking like a bit of a pane. is it better to use a label and html? or some other approach?

Comment: *"is a monospaced font a good way to format the pane?"* Good/bad are very opinion oriented views when it comes to presentation, but as far as opinions go, I think only numeric values should be displayed using a mono-spaced font (to make the digits align). *"is it better to use a label and html?"* In this case, an HTML based `table` is able to organise data in columns and rows and allows for styling to specify the alignment of each datum within the respective table cell, so it would be able to align the first column to the left, and the 2nd to the right.

Comment: yeah, that's kind of the impression i got when messing about with it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String[][] data = {
    {"Name:", "Mr Nick Woodward"},
    {"City:", "Reading"},
    {"Long:", "Supercalafragalisticexpyaladocious"},
};

private String getTable() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html><table>");

    for (String[] row : data) {
        sb.append("<tr>");
        sb.append("<td>");
        sb.append(row[0]);
        sb.append("</td>");
        sb.append("<td style='text-align: right;'>");
        sb.append(row[1]);
        sb.append("</td>");
        sb.append("</tr>");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

[image]

Comment: i may have had a beer or two at this point, but this looks great, thanks!